# How to fix plugin issue with Vysor on CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm trying to start Vysor on CentOS. There two different ways: one. is two use chrome addon. but the error that I'm receiving "Windows Crash: !context_->is_null():  "
Second. I've got application from git but it typing that plugin not installing.

I'm Using Centos7. android MI_A2_lite connected to USB.
ADB tool installed

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Google Chrome

2) Type chrome://flags in the address bar

3) search "Override software rendering list",

4) Now click on Enable

5)  restart the browser.

6) Go to chrome://settings in address bar

7) search for "Use hardware acceleration"

8) enable

7) restart Chrome